# Solr DIH: Nested documents ignored by Child Transformer (not ignored using json endpoint)

Tags: solr

**Shortly**

- When I import data using `DIH`  stored into a relation database (using `child=true`), nested documents are NOT attached when `fl=*,[child]`.
- When I import same data, structured as `json` documents (using `/update/json/docs` endpoint), nested documents are attached.

Short issues:

1. `"_childDocuments_":[]` on debug `DIH` execution.
2. Only `_root_` is populated. According to documentation `_nest_path_` should be populated automatically as well.
3. Nested documents are not returned with parent when `fl=*,[child]`

**Detailed problem**

**SQL Data**:

`Parents`:

```sql
SELECT '1' AS id,
   'parent-name-1' AS name_s,
   'parent' AS node_type_s
```

```
+----+---------------+-------------+
| id |    name_s     | node_type_s |
+----+---------------+-------------+
|  1 | parent-name-1 | parent      |
+----+---------------+-------------+
```

`Children`:

```sql
SELECT '1-1' AS id,
       '1' AS parent_id_s,
       'child-name-1' AS name_s,
       'child' AS node_type_s
UNION
SELECT '2-1' AS id,
       '1' AS parent_id_s,
       'child-name-2' AS name_s,
       'child' AS node_type_s
```

```
+-----+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| id  | parent_id_s |    name_s    | node_type_s |
+-----+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| 1-1 |           1 | child-name-1 | child       |
| 2-1 |           1 | child-name-2 | child       |
+-----+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

**Same data in json**:

```json
{
   "id":"1",
   "name_s":"parent-name-1",
   "node_type_s":"parent",
   "children":[
      {
         "id":"1-1",
         "parent_id_s":"1",
         "name_s":"child-name-1",
         "node_type_s":"child"
      },
      {
         "id":"2-1",
         "parent_id_s":"1",
         "name_s":"child-name-2",
         "node_type_s":"child"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Importing data with `DIH`**:

Here my `DIH` configuration:

```xml
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource
        driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        url="jdbc:sqlserver://${dataimporter.request.host};databaseName=${dataimporter.request.database}"
        user="${dataimporter.request.user}"
        password="${dataimporter.request.password}"
    />

    <document>
        <entity
        name="parent"
        query="SELECT '1' AS id,
                'parent-name-1' AS name_s,
                'parent' AS node_type_s">

            <field column="node_type_s"/>
            <field column="id"/>
            <field column="name_s"/>

            <entity
            name="children"
            child="true"
            cacheKey="parent_id_s" cacheLookup="parent.id" cacheImpl="SortedMapBackedCache"
            query="SELECT '1-1' AS id,
                    '1' AS parent_id_s,
                    'child-name-1' AS name_s,
                    'child' AS node_type_s
                UNION
                SELECT '2-1' AS id,
                    '1' AS parent_id_s,
                    'child-name-2' AS name_s,
                    'child' AS node_type_s">

                <field column="node_type_s"/>
                <field column="id"/>
                <field column="parent_id_s"/>
                <field column="name_s"/>

            </entity>

        </entity>

    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

After having imported `DIH`, here the response:

```json
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":396
   },
   "initArgs":[
      "defaults",
      [
         "config",
         "parent-children-config-straightforward.xml"
      ]
   ],
   "command":"full-import",
   "mode":"debug",
   "documents":[
      {
         "name_s":"parent-name-1",
         "node_type_s":"parent",
         "id":"1",
         "_version_":1683338565872779300,
         "_root_":"1",
         "_childDocuments_":[
            
         ]
      }
   ],
   "verbose-output":[
      
   ],
   "status":"idle",
   "importResponse":"",
   "statusMessages":{
      "Total Requests made to DataSource":"2",
      "Total Rows Fetched":"3",
      "Total Documents Processed":"1",
      "Total Documents Skipped":"0",
      "Full Dump Started":"2020-11-14 12:25:55",
      "":"Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 1 documents. Deleted 0 documents.",
      "Committed":"2020-11-14 12:25:56",
      "Time taken":"0:0:0.365"
   }
}
```

Two issues here:

1. As you can see `"_childDocuments_":[]`. Why is it empty?
2. Only `_root_` is populated. According to documentation `_nest_path_` should be populated as well.

**Asking for documents**

After having imported documents I've tried to retrive them, first using `q=*:*`:

```json
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":0,
      "params":{
         "q":"*:*",
         "_":"1605355606189"
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "numFound":3,
      "start":0,
      "numFoundExact":true,
      "docs":[
         {
            "name_s":"child-name-1",
            "node_type_s":"child",
            "parent_id_s":"1",
            "id":"1-1",
            "_version_":1683338565872779264
         },
         {
            "name_s":"child-name-2",
            "node_type_s":"child",
            "parent_id_s":"1",
            "id":"2-1",
            "_version_":1683338565872779264
         },
         {
            "name_s":"parent-name-1",
            "node_type_s":"parent",
            "id":"1",
            "_version_":1683338565872779264
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

All right, all documents are present.

**Getting parent with its children**:

`q=id:1` and `fl=*,[child]`:

```json
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":0,
      "params":{
         "q":"id:1",
         "fl":"*,[child]",
         "_":"1605355606189"
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "numFound":1,
      "start":0,
      "numFoundExact":true,
      "docs":[
         {
            "name_s":"parent-name-1",
            "node_type_s":"parent",
            "id":"1",
            "_version_":1683338565872779264
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Other issue arises here:

3. Only parent is returned, wihout nested documents.

**JSON approach**:

After having spent several days strugling with above issues, I tried to import same documents using `json` endpoint using above json data.

After having imported them, I've performed the same above query:

```json
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":2,
      "params":{
         "q":"id:1",
         "fl":"*,[child]",
         "_":"1605355606189"
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "numFound":1,
      "start":0,
      "numFoundExact":true,
      "docs":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "name_s":"parent-name-1",
            "node_type_s":"parent",
            "_version_":1683339728909238272,
            "children":[
               {
                  "id":"1-1",
                  "parent_id_s":"1",
                  "name_s":"child-name-1",
                  "node_type_s":"child",
                  "_version_":1683339728909238272
               },
               {
                  "id":"2-1",
                  "parent_id_s":"1",
                  "name_s":"child-name-2",
                  "node_type_s":"child",
                  "_version_":1683339728909238272
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see, nested documents are returned.

Why?

Please any ideas?

Comment: I posted this on reddit on your question but didn't get an answer, so I'm posting it here as well: When using DIH the child/parent support is meant to be used with the block join query parser. In effect the child-parameter tells DIH to index the rows as separate documents instead of as fields in the original document. The JSON endpoint however indexes things as more modern and "proper" Child documents, where the Child transformer works as expected and where the root and nest paths gets populated.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh .I think I got feed back on reedit. We're moving to json endpoint. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm getting same issues using SolrJ. I've added information into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64875133/solrj-is-not-nesting-documents). Could you please take a look on that?

Comment: @Jordi Did you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same issue and didn't able to find a solution.